# How do I use JSONSchema to accept any object string value, regardless of its key?

Tags: jsonschema

I have a system that is receiving JSON messages which contain metadata from a static analysis of a file. The names of these fields are dynamically generated from the scan and can be any valid string, but the value is always a valid string.

e.g.

```
{
    "filename": "hello.txt",
    ...
    "meta": {
        "some file property": "any string",
        "some other file property": "another string",
        ...
    }
}
```

I have no way of knowing what the keys in meta will be before receiving the message, nor do I know how many keys there will be. Is there a way of capturing in a JSONSchema that it doesn't matter what keys are present, so long as their values are always strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`additionalProperties`](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.5.6)

> Validation with "additionalProperties" applies only to the child
>   values of instance names that do not match any names in "properties",
>   and do not match any regular expression in "patternProperties".

The value of additionalProperties can be a JSON Schema, like so

```
...
"additionalProperties" : {
  "type": "string"
}
...
```

Feel free to let me know if I've missed anything in my explanation, or ask any further questions.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for accepting my answer. JSON Schema has a Slack channel if you want to discuss any issues which fall outside of those you can ask about here.